# Saving location of cursor in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

I have a contenteditable div. I am trying to implement "on-the-fly syntax highlighting". Here's what I have so far:

```js
const codeElement = document.getElementById('code');

// func to apply highlighting
function highlight() {
  const controlRegex = /\b(function|const|let)\b/g;
  const stringRegex = /["'].*["']/g;
  const functionCallRegex = /[a-zA-Z_\d]*\([^)]*\)/g;
  const constantRegex = /.*[a-zA-Z_\d]+\./g;

  codeElement.innerHTML = codeElement.textContent.replace(stringRegex,
    '<span style="color: #0d0; font-weight: normal;">$&</span>')
    .replace(controlRegex, '<span style="color: pink;">$&</span>')
    .replace(functionCallRegex, '<span style="color: #0bb; font-weight: bold;">$&</span>')
    .replace(constantRegex, '<span style="color: yellow;">$&</span>');
}


codeElement.addEventListener('input', highlight);
highlight();
```

It works well, except for one problem. Whenever I press a key, it moves the cursor to the start of the div again.

I tried using the combination of `window.getSelection` and `document.createRange` to move the cursor to the end of the div whenever a key is pressed, but that raises issues when editing something that's not the last character.

Comment: Since you will be replacing the innerHTML, this is going to be an issue. The best way is to learn how to work with all the nodes and actually add nodes, move text nodes around etc... instead of blanket replacing HTML, because it will be hard to find your location again.

Comment: @somethinghere How do I do that though?

Comment: This is a very complicated thing to build, to be honest, but it basically comes down to using the selection and range APIs to nest your textNodes into new nodes, move text nodes, using treewalkers to collect text nodes... This is a whole huge field in JS, and it's not going to be that easy. But it would be neat. The alternative is to put your innerHTML in a seperate, exactly the same, box and make it unselectable, then giving your original box `color: transparent`, which should keep the carret available. Then you just need to sync the visualisation and the source code...

Comment: @somethinghere Ok, the second suggestion worked. Thank you

Comment: Cool, I would be curious to see your answer if you're willing to share! :)

Comment: @somethinghere I posted my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by keeping a `div` that had the highlighting function, and overlayed on top of it a `textarea` with `color: transparent` and `caret-color: white` used for input.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
const codeElement = document.getElementById("code");


function onInput(evt) {
  const cInput = evt.target.value;

  // func to apply highlighting
  const controlRegex = /\b(function|const|let)\b/g;
  const stringRegex = /["'].*["']/g;
  const functionCallRegex = /[a-zA-Z_\d]*\([^)]*\)/g;
  const constantRegex = /.*[a-zA-Z_\d]+\./g;

  codeElement.innerHTML = cInput.replace(stringRegex,
      '<span style="color: #0d0; font-weight: normal;">$&</span>')
    .replace(controlRegex, '<span style="color: pink;">$&</span>')
    .replace(functionCallRegex, '<span style="color: #0bb; font-weight: bold;">$&</span>')
    .replace(constantRegex, '<span style="color: yellow;">$&</span>');
}


inputElement.addEventListener('input', onInput);
inputElement.focus();
```

```css
pre#code,
#input {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -50px;
  ;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  padding: 60px 20px;
}

#input {
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: white;
  background: transparent;
}

pre#code {
  padding-top: calc(60px - 1em);
}
```

```html
<pre id="code"></pre>
<textarea id="input" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```